# How does the inverse image of a sphere under a higher dimensional linear maps looks like?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a linear map $A : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R ^k$, with k < n, with $A$ full rank. Let us assume that I have a sphere $\mathbb S^k(r,x) \in \mathbb R^k$ of centre $x$ and radius $r$.

How does the set of points $x \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $Ax \in \mathbb S^k(r,x)$  look like? Is it isomorphic to $\mathbb S^k(r,x) \times \mathbb R^{n-k}$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $k > n$?

Comment: $A$ cannot be invertible in this set-up (with $k\not=n$).

Comment: Sorry, I was definitely wrong. Just edited!

Comment: Hint: Decompose $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a direct sum of the kernel of $A$ and its orthogonal component.  You'll see more of the structure in that way.

Comment: Correction to the title: This is not the *image* of a sphere under a linear map, it is the *inverse image*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose first that $A:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ is an invertible map.  We first want to determine what the preimage of a sphere is in this case.

Points on a sphere satisfy $\sum x_i^2=1$.  Then, $y$ is in the preimage of the sphere if and only if $\sum (Ay)_i^2=1$.  This equation can be rewritten as 
$
y^TA^TAy=1.
$
Let $B=A^TA$.  Note that $B$ is a symmetric and positive definite matrix.  Then, $B$ can be diagonalized as $B=P^TDP$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose elements are the eigenvalues of $B$ (which are all positive).  Moreover, $P$ is an orthogonal matrix.  Since $P$ is an orthogonal matrix, $P$ is a change of coordinates of $y$, so let $z$ be the coordinates of $y$ after the change of coordinates under $P$.  Then, the points of interest satisfy
$
\sum \lambda_i z_i^2=1.
$
Where the $\lambda_i$'s are the eigenvalues of $B$.  Since all of the eigenvalues are positive, this set describes an ellipsoid.  Therefore, the preimage of a sphere is homeomorphic (ambient isotopic) to a sphere.

Now, let's consider $A:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^k$ where $A$ is full rank and $n\geq k$.  Let $K$ be the kernel of $A$.  Then, we can write $\mathbb{R}^n=K\oplus K^{\perp}$, using any appropriate norm.  Observe that $K^{\perp}\simeq\mathbb{R}^k$ and there is an invertible matrix $A':K^{\perp}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ such that if $(k_1,k_2)\in K\oplus K^{\perp}$, $A(k_1,k_2)=A'k_2$.  Moreover, since $A$ is full rank, $A'$ is invertible, so the preimage of a sphere in $K^\perp$ is an ellipsoid.  Finally, for $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$ and $k$ is its preimage in $K^\perp$, then its preimage in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $K\oplus\{k\}$.  Therefore, the preimage of a sphere is $(K\oplus\text{ellipsoid})$.  Since $K\simeq\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$, your claim holds.